# Need ASP.NET web site architecture to appear generic to the user

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, returnurl

Our security team would like our .NET 2.0 website to appear generic to the user, not indicating any particular architecture. "ReturnURL" indicates an ASP.NET website. (Hiding .ASPX in the address bar is a related request.)

I have already figured out how to hide response headers. Not sure how to hide the things I mentioned above. Is it possible?  Do I need to redesign the site?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: How is `returnUrl` this a security risk?

Comment: The simplest hack would be to reload or redirect to the login page after landing on it. TBH, most of the other questions are off the mark. And people are not writing their own security.

Comment: @Dai I restructured my post to read more clearly for my situation.

Comment: @wazz Thanks for your input. You're right about my questions being off the mark. 
 They were the result of some frustration I felt at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can change much in 2.0. Later versions have a thing called 'Friendly URLs' that make urls look like mvc urls, with no file extension. As others have said, changing these things won't *really* help with security.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using owin? if you do, you can remove returnUrl, but there is nothing about security on that

```
    //Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        //your code
        //...
        //...
    }
```